# How to replace list item content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to make a button that will replace the content of a li. I've searched other answers on here, but I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object li#element2 has no method 'replaceWith'

I've tried replaceWith, .html, and .text, but they all have the same Here's my page:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#theButton").click(function(){
("li#element2").replaceWith("This is the second element")
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1 id="header">The document header.</h1>


<p>Value: <input type="text" id="theInput" value="" size=10>


<ul id="theList">
<li id="element1">Element 1
<li id="element2">Element 2
<li id="element3">Element 3
</ul>

<div id="theDiv"></div>

<input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!""></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not forget to close your `<li>` tags. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typo

missing `$` sign

```
$("#element2").replaceWith("This is the second element");
^
```

[**fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FjMv/)

---

Commented by  [NicoSantangelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437049/nicosantangelo)

You also don't need  `$("li#element2")` it will be faster with `$("#element2")` as id is unique so don't have to use tag selector with it.

---

Better use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

[**fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FjMv/1)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#theButton").click(function () {
        $("#element2").text("This is the second element")
    });
});
```

---

Correct your markup close `li` tags

```
<ul id="theList">
  <li id="element1">Element 1</li>
  <li id="element2">Element 2</li>
  <li id="element3">Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `"li#element2"` === `"#element2"` just more "expensive"

Comment: @NicoSantangelo ty i didn't see that lol ..!! But updated answer now.